# expressjs: how can I use bodyParser only for a specific resource?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using expressjs, I would like to use the body Parser only for specific resource, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`app.use()` [allows you to specify a "mount path"](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use), as well as which middleware to mount, so you should be able to get away with;

```
app.use('/foo', express.bodyParser);
```

As `express.bodyParser` [returns a function](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html) whose signature is `req, res, next` (as with all middleware), this seems analagous to adding it as a handler to a resource;

```
app.get('/foo', express.bodyParser);
app.get('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
    // req has been parsed.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Matt answer is good, you can optimize its syntax by writing:

```
app.get('/foo', express.bodyParser, function (req, res, next) {
    // parsed request
});
```